# Explanation for behaviour of code

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I was following the multithreading tutorial from 
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads and experimenting with some of the code provided.

I used this source file https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/hello.c
then added this to the main function:

```
   void * v;
   v = (void *)t;
```

and replaced this line:

```
rc = pthread_create(threads+t, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)t);
```

by this:

```
rc = pthread_create(threads+t, NULL, PrintHello, v)
```

Arguably(I know it's not a good argument :) ), the output should have remained unchanged..
but this is the new output:

```
In main: creating thread 0
In main: creating thread 1
Hello World! It's me, thread #140734232544832!
In main: creating thread 2
In main: creating thread 3
Hello World! It's me, thread #140734232544832!
In main: creating thread 4
Hello World! It's me, thread #140734232544832!
Hello World! It's me, thread #140734232544832!
Hello World! It's me, thread #140734232544832!
```

Thread # is garbage!

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? Why is the output changed?

Is it because t was being passed by value and casted while being passed to PrintHello while now, after the change I am attempting to pass pointer and while the address of that pointer is passed properly - that address does not contain the value t contains since that was local to main?

Can someone please confirm/ reject and fix my theory?

Comment: you need to show us where you added `void* v` and the follwing line in the main

Comment: ah, of course. v gets the value of t. which right after `long t`, `t` has an undefined value. put it inside the for loop instead.

Comment: Thanks pippin1289. I had completely ignored the most common suspicion and was wondering instead if this was due to casting at the time of calling the function - which of course was an invalid suspicion.

After moving the     v = (void *)t into the loop it works the way I expected it to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments you need to change your code from:

```
long t;
void* v;
v = (void *)t;
for(...)
  //stuff
```

to:

```
long t;
for(...) {
  void* v;
  v = (void*) t;
  //stuff
}
```

Basically what was happening in the prior case is that t is uninitialized and thus its value is undefined. Then it is copied into a variable v and passed into the pthread. If it is inside the for loop, than t has been initialized.

Comment: yeah. Got it. I replied to your comment above. Thanks very much!